# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. How to use ONE field for SIX columns on a search in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

How can I add a custom filter or create a custom search field with ActiveAdmin?

I need to generate a report on wire transfers. There are these fields in the Invoices model

- wire_transfer_1_ar
- wire_transfer_2_ar
- wire_transfer_3_ar
- wire_transfer_1_customer
- wire_transfer_2_customer
- wire_transfer_3_customer

So I have this

```
filter :wire_transfer_1_ar
filter :wire_transfer_2_ar
filter :wire_transfer_3_ar
filter :wire_transfer_1_customer
filter :wire_transfer_2_customer
filter :wire_transfer_2_customer
```

So when a wire transfer is found, then I can click a link to generate a report.

How can I use only ONE field, to search for all those 6 fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveAdmin is using [metasearch gem](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) inside, so you can do this way:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do

  filter :title_or_name_or_description_contains, :as => :string

end
```

Comment: AA no longer uses Metasearch and now uses Ransack, but it seems to still support this kind of filter. In my testing, you need to explicitly state `as: :string`.

You can also pass `label: "Custom Label"` if you want a different label.